# Looping a Function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, loops

total newbie here. I'm having problems looping a function that I've created. I'm having some problems copying the code over but I'll give a general idea of it:

```
function[X]=Test(A,B,C,D)

other parts of the code
.
.
.


X = linsolve(K,L) 
end
```

where K,L are other matrices I derived from the 4 variables A,B,C,D

The problem is whenever I execute the function Test(1,2,3,4), I can only get one answer out. I'm trying to loop this process for one variable, keep the other 3 variables constant.

For example, I want to get answers for A = 1:10, while B = 2, C = 3, D = 4

I've tried the following method and they did not work:

```
Function[X] = Test(A,B,C,D)
for A = 1:10

other parts of the code...
X=linsolve(K,L)
end
```

Whenever I keyed in the command Test(1,2,3,4), it only gave me the output of Test(10,2,3,4)

Then I read somewhere that you have to call the function from somewhere else, so I edited the Test function to be Function[X] = Test(B,C,D) and left A out where it can be assigned in another script eg:

```
global A
for A = 1:10
    Test(A,2,3,4)
end
```

But this gives an error as well, as Test function requires A to be defined. As such I'm a little lost and can't seem to find any information on how can this be done. Would appreciate all the help I can get.

Cheers guys

Comment: Either run the function in the loop, or run the loop in the function and return an array (not a single value). I don't see what `global` has to do with it.

Comment: @Bernhard How would you return an array when you run the loop in the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
A=1:10;    B=2;    C=3;    D=4;
%Do pre-allocation for X according to the dimensions of your output
for iter = 1:length(A)
    X(:,:,iter)= Test(A(iter),B,C,D);
end
X
```

where

```
function [X]=Test(A,B,C,D)
%other parts of the code
X = linsolve(K,L) 
end
```

Comment: Hi Sadar_Usama,

Thanks for the code, it works but this code gave out the following outputs

X(:,:,1)

X(:,:,1)
X(:,:,2)

X(:,:,1)
X(:,:,2)
X(:,:,3)

X(:,:,1)
X(:,:,2)
X(:,:,3)
X(:,:,4)

and so on.. until 
X(:,:,1)
.
.
X(:,:,10)

Is there a way to jump straight to the last set of outputs?

Cheers

Comment: Sorry, I pressed enter by accident before I could finished typing my question

Comment: @dljw I don't understand. Are you asking that you want to see the output when A=10 i.e. `X(:,:,10)` only?

Comment: No, I want to see output of X(:,:,1) . . X(:,:,10), but the code above gives me the output  X(:,:,1), X(:,:,1) X(:,:,2), X(:,:,1) X(:,:,2) X(:,:,3), X(:,:,1) X(:,:,2) X(:,:,3) X(:,:,4), .... until X(:,:,1) . . X(:,:,10)

Comment: @dljw Oh I get it now. What you're asking for is a semi-colon. I have edited the answer. Try the edited answer!

Comment: I added the semicolon but now when I run the script the only output that comes out is: Untitled2 (which is the name of the script)

Comment: @dljw Did you write `X` at the end of the loop just like I did in my  edited code above? Try the edited code. This will work

Comment: Oh yes, it works now my bad! Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function X = Test(A,B,C,D)
% allocate output (it is faster than changing the size in every loop)
X = {};
% loop for each position in A
for i = 1:numel(A);
    %in the other parts you have to use A(i) instead of just A
    ... other parts of code
    %overwrite the value in X at position i
    X{i} = linsolve(K,L);
end
end
```

and run it with Test(1:10,2,3,4)

To answer what went wrong before:
When you loop with 'for A=1:10' you overwrite the A that was passed to the function (so the function will ignore the A that you passed it) and in each loop you overwrite the X calculated in the previous loop (that is why you can only see the answer for A=10).
The second try should work if you have created a file named Test.m with the function X = (A,B,C,D) as the first code in the file. Although the global assignment is unnecessary. In fact I would strongly recommend you not to use global variables as it gets very messy very fast.

Comment: If `linsolve` gives output whose size is other than 1x1, this solution, I don't think will work

Comment: Hi Joel, I tried the code above but it doesn't seem to work

I got something along the lines of 

    X = [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

The error message that came out said:
Error using ^, Inputs must be scalar and a square matrix.
To compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead. I think it'll be quite troublesome for me to change all the power in my code as I use it quite a lot in it.

Comment: @dljw did you change all A to A(i) inside the loop? If not you could try that. I also changed the code to adress Sardar's comment by putting it into a cell.